# How to make a collapse text view using pure Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

1. Hide the overflow text if it's over 3 lines, and present a "show"/"hide" button below.
2. If text is in 3 lines(3、2、1 lines), do not present "show"/"hide" button.

Is there any way to accomplish this by using pure just Reactjs(not jquery)?

Comment: I'd just suggest with experimenting with `oninput` and `setState` as a start

Comment: Why `onInput`? There are no input event.

Comment: you're basically just asking for code. Why don't you try working out how to do it outside of react first, then apply it into there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not giving you a perfect solution but this may help you.

I have created a **Test** component in react which receives the text paragraph as child element. 
If paragraph length is greater than 3 then you will see show hide button other wise it will be displayed as it is.

How to get number of lines?
I have set the line-height to 1 em and height to 3.3 em so now div will allow only three lines.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
        height:'3.3em'
     };
   }

  countLines = () => {
    let height = this.testComp.offsetHeight;   
    if ( (height - 2 ) / 16 > 3.3 ) {
       this.setState({showButton:true});
    }
  }
  
  showHidePara=() => {
     if (this.state.height == 'auto') {
        this.setState({height:'3.3em'});
     } else {
        this.setState({height:'auto'});
     }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
      this.countLines();
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
    < div>
        { this.state.showButton ? 
       <button onClick={this.showHidePara}> Show/hide </button>
    : null
    }
    <div id ="parent" style={{height:this.state.height}}>

      <div id = "content" ref={(c) => this.testComp = c } style={{height:'auto'}}>
         {this.props.children}
      </div> 
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const Comp = () => (
<div>
<h3> Test 1 </h3>
<hr/>
  <Test> 
 This is a test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line.This is a test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line.This is a test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line..This is a test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line.This is a test line.This is a large test line.This is a large test line.
</Test>
<hr/>
<h3> Test 2 </h3>
<hr/>
<Test> This is a test line.This is a large test line.
</Test>
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render( <Comp /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
#content {
    width:auto;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}

#parent {
     border : 1px solid red;
     overflow : hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```